# Was Mark A Scribe?

Tags: mark

Given that the ability to write was an unusual skill in the time of the composition of the Gospels, would Mark have been likely to have been a scribe?  I mean if the tradition of Peter dictating to Mark is true, would Mark have had professional training in acting as an amanuensis?

Comment: That's a good, but difficult question.  Note that even the best answer will amount to informed speculation, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am having trouble finding citations for this, so maybe some of the more erudite members of this list can help me out, but: I have read from a few sources that Mark's spelling, grammar, and overall Greek style are just about at the bottom of the barrel of the New Testament, a spot probably shared by *Revelation*.  This being the case (and I'm assuming it is, based on my memory, not on any citations I can find readily available), I doubt that Mark had any professional training at all.  I would *guess* that he was someone who had to have to some kind of minimal literacy in order to fulfill whatever professional role he may have had -- some kind of business proprietor, or a low-level government functionary, or ...

Answer (score 0):

Is this Mark not the same Mark that was with Paul & Barnabas in the book of Acts 12:12, 12:25, 15:36-39, and again in 2Timothy 4:11.
If so when Paul asked for Mark, was he not to take dictation from Paul seeing Paul was having difficulties seeing.
ּ

Comment: Seems to me that’s the question—is it the same person.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).